# tkinter keeps crashing when I call pyautogui commmand

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

I have been recently trying to make simple program working with tkinter and pyautogui the pyautogui
one alone with no tkinter just works fine but when I decided to start making them into tkinter with GUI it keeps crashing I think that the reason why is this happening that the button just keeps being pressed even if I have typed `root.update()` it appears to be not pressed any more  but it is pressed and doing the command.

The code with no tkinter that works:

```
import pyautogui,time
time.sleep(5)
f = open("mytext.txt", 'r')
time.sleep(5)
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
```

With tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui,time
root = tk.Tk()
def stop_writing():
    global btn 
    btn.config(command = None)
def write():
    root.update()

    time.sleep(5)
    f = open("mytext.txt", 'r')

    for word in f:
        pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.mainloop()

btn = tk.Button(root, text = "start writing" , command = write)
btn.pack()     
btn_disable = tk.Button(root, text = "stop writing" ,command = stop_writing)
btn_disable.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to stop  it from crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to stop Tkinter from crashing is by not using `time.sleep` in the main thread.

I suggest you create a separate thread for `pyautogui.typewrite`. Also, note you are not supposed to update Tkinter components from different thread as Tkinter is not thread-safe.

I will be showing how you can do this using multi-threading.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui,time, threading


def stop_writing():
    global _stop, thread
    if thread:
        _stop = True
        thread.join()

def write():
    
    time.sleep(2)
    with open(r"file.txt", 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()

    for word in content:
        if _stop:
            return
        pyautogui.typewrite(word)


def start():
    global thread, _stop

    if thread and thread.is_alive():
        stop_writing()

    thread = None
    thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
    thread.daemon = True
    _stop = False
    thread.start()
    

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: [stop_writing(), root.destroy()])
_stop = False
thread = None

btn = tk.Button(root, text = "start writing" , command = start)
btn.pack()     
btn_disable = tk.Button(root, text = "stop writing" ,command = stop_writing)
btn_disable.pack()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can also make use of `root.after` and call your write function after some seconds.

Some minor mistakes:

1. You should always close a file if you open it.
2. I checked pyautogui documentation and I couldn't find any method such as mainloop